# Внезапно заставить выполнить потоки какое либо действие

Tags: c#, winforms

Десятки потоков выполняют один и тот же метод

```
private void ZapuskPotokov(int viborKolPotokov) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < viborKolPotokov; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        new Thread(() => Algoritm(j, viborKolPotokov)).Start();
    }
}
```

Но в какой то внезапный момент, есть необходимость, выполнить ими то, чего нет в том методе и затем их завершить. Как заставить их это сделать ?

Comment: Никак. Единственный вариант выполнить код в потоке - действительно выполнить его в потоке. Никак "подсунуть" снаружи код не получится.

Comment: @PashaPash Т.е. что то ему передать - переменную например - и когда он дойдёт до проверки этой переменной, а там значение которое я подсунул и заготовленный заранее код под эту переменную, он станет выполнять ? Так как то ? А как тогда передать в эти дочерние потоки значение ? Знаю как из них, а вот наоборот...

Comment: у вас же прямо в вопросе две переменные захватываются потоком. Добавьте третью (в виде поля класса)

Comment: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). Когда поток получает запрос на отмену - выполняет некое дополнительное действие и завершается.

Comment: Попробовать передать в метод Action или Func

Comment: Пока решил использовать глобальную переменную - не знаю на сколько это правильно, пока работает.

Comment: Без [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) - неправильно. Ну или чтение/запись/изменение этой переменной должно с помощью специальных методов выполняться.

Comment: Async - await?
Можно в текущем потоке делать проверку асинхронно. Проверять содержание какой-то переменной, например. Параллельно запустить ваши N потоков. Как только содержимое переменной изменяется, завершаются потоки из асинхронного.